# Choosing two numbers with one being less than the other

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have to choose two numbers, $a$ and $b$. The first number, $a$, can be $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,$ or $7$. The second number, $b$, can be $2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,$ or $8$. My condition is that the first number $a$ must be less than the second number, $b$. How many possible combinations are there?

It is given that $(3,4)$ is different from $(4,3)$ but $(4,4)$ is not different from $(4,4)$.

I have tried using casework but that has gotten me all tied up. The inequality is what is throwing me off.

Comment: Can you show us how the inequality throws you off during the casework?

Comment: Never mind, I understand it now thanks to @JMoravitz. Thank you! I was just confused about how to confront the _a<b_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case 1: $a<b$

To answer how many ways we can have $a<b$, we note that we can find all such cases by picking two numbers from the list $1,2,\dots,8$ and the smaller number will be our "$a$".  (Note, by doing so, we avoid having $b$ be one and $a$ be eight)

> There are then $\binom{8}{2}$ such possibilities in this case.

---

In the case that you wish to only consider the cases where $a<b$, then case $1$ is the interesting one above.  For curiousities sake, we can compute the number of cases where $a=b$ or where $b<a$ below.

---

Case 2: $a=b$

The only ways here are if $a=b=2$ or $3$ or $\dots$ or $7$

> for a total of $6$ possibilities in this case.

Case 3: $a>b$

If $a$ is greater than $b$, we know that $a$ cannot be $8$ and $b$ cannot be $1$, but otherwise it is very similar to case $1$.  This is equivalent to picking two distinct numbers from the list $2,3,\dots,7$ and the smaller of the two being our choice for "$b$".

> for a total of $\binom{6}{2}$ in this case.

---

> for a grand total of $\binom{8}{2}+\binom{6}{2}+6 = 49 = 7\cdot 7$.  Note, that this agrees with what we would have expected from multiplication principle since there are seven choices for $a$ and seven choices for $b$.

Comment: I think case 1 is the one the OP is interested in.

Comment: @user84413 Good catch.  I kinda ran on autopilot there.  It feels strange that he included the lines "(4,3) is different than (3,4) but (4,4) is the same as (4,4)."

Comment: You gave a good answer; it was just more complete than the OP probably expected.

Comment: Yes, I am only interested in case 1, but thank you for your answer!